# how to reload the div using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In the Page there are two buttons the btnCall button hides the hideDiv. and Button1 shows the hideDiv. Now inside the div there is a button Button2 which shows some text.

when i click the Button2 it shows some text in a Label. Then if i hide the div all of it hides. Then when i make the div visible then it shows the div. But The text in the label is visible though i have not yet clicked the button. I dont want the Label to show any text. I can do it by making the label text an empty string. I dont want to do that. I want to reload the div so that nothing shows in label unless i click the Button2.

How do i do that?

my aspx code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="btnCall" runat="server" Text="Call1" OnClick="btnCall_Click" />

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button2" />

    <div class="hideDiv">
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</form>
```

code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btnCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();

    strScript.Append("$(document).ready(function(){");
    strScript.Append("$(\".hideDiv\").hide();");
    strScript.Append("});");

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", strScript.ToString(), true);
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
    strScript.Append("$(document).ready(function(){");
    strScript.Append("$(\".hideDiv\").show();");
    strScript.Append("});");

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", strScript.ToString(), true);
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       Label1.Text = "Some Text";
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're doing things on the server side that should be happening on the client side. If you use a button's OnClientClick event and return false from JavaScript, you can directly execute JavaScript functions without causing a postback.

Comment: mason how to do it on server side?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my point. You don't need this to happen on server side, because it requires no server interaction. Trying to do it from the server side is just going to unnecessarily complicate things. Try to do it purely on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of a "reset" feature. And you need to write everything on the client.

Something like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <input type="button" id="btntoggle" value="show"/>
    <br/>
    <div id="hideDiv">
        <input type="button" id="btnshow" value="show text"/>
        <br/>
        <label id="text">Some text</label>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Js:

```
$(function(){
    reset();
    $('#btntoggle').click(function(){
        $('#hideDiv').toggle();
        if($(this).val() == 'show')
            $(this).val('hide');                       
        else{
            $(this).val('show');
            reset();
        }
    });

    $('#btnshow').click(function(){
        $('#text').show();
    });

    function reset(){
        $('#hideDiv').hide();
        $('#text').hide();            
    }

});
```

Js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9nkFf/

### Alternative:

You can do everything from the server side. And I've come to realize that must be what your want. But you'll still need some kind of a "reset" logic on the server side. For this, consider setting `hideDiv` as a server control - preferably a `Panel`; you can toggle its visibility.

Say your aspx looks like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="btnCall" runat="server" Text="Call1" OnClick="btnCall_Click" />

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button2" />

    <asp:Panel id="hideDiv" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>
</form>
```

Code behind will look much simpler:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btnCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    reset();
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hideDiv.Visible = true;    
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Some Text";
    Label1.Visible = true;
} 

void reset()
{
    Label1.Visible = hideDiv.Visible = false;   
}
```